# How do I decompile a Python program compiled by `bbfreeze`? Python Unfrozen Binary Decompile Error - No Module Named Decompilers

Tags: python, decompiling

I have recently tried to decompile a Python program compiled by `bbfreeze`.

I used this:

https://github.com/Katharsis/unfrozen_binary

When I try to run it, I get the following error: "No Module named decompilers."

I tried using `pip install decompilers` in the command prompt.

But there is no module named `decompilers`.

The errors seem to come from the `commons` file in the unfrozen_binary.

I also tried to use pyThaw here https://github.com/bannsec/pyThaw.

But I'm getting a fatal error saying that "afta cant run in debugger mode".

How do I decompile a Python program compiled by `bbfreeze`?

Comment: // , Add some whitespace, formatting and a better title. Hope I didn't screw up the intent here

Comment: Did you install all the dependencies listed in the README document?